# Быстрый cкриншот экрана

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, скриншот

У меня проблема с оптимизацией кода. Моя программа каждый тик делает скриншот экрана и копирует из неё участок для атрибута bitmap.

```
Graphics bmpGraphics;
Bitmap bitmap;
Bitmap GetScreen()
{
 using (bmpGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
 {
  rp = Form1.regionPos;//l_pos
  bmpGraphics.CopyFromScreen(rp.X, rp.Y, 0, 0, new Size(390, 50));
 }
 Thread.Sleep(1);
 return bitmap;
}
```

При запуске программы, производительность компьютера снижается почти в два раза. Возможно потому, что изначально получаю изображения всего экрана, а потом вырезаю из неё нужный участок.

Как можно ускорить приложение?

Comment: А как часто вы вызываете вашу функцию?

Comment: @VladD
"каждый тик"
...

Comment: @dthpth: Тогда неудивительно :-)

Comment: По-видимому, у вас проблема на гораздо более высоком уровне, нежели оптимизация. Зачем вам *каждый тик* делать скриншот?

Answer (score 1):

Вот код взятия скриншота с куска экрана...

```
public Bitmap TakeScreenshot(Rectangle rect)
{
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        g.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        return bmp;
}
```

Но у вас проблема глобальнее и это вас не особо то и спасет. Измените период между тиками на более большой период как минимум (подберите оптимальный размер)

И вообще задумайтесь реально ли оно нужно.=) Может, возможно достичь нужного результата и без этого.